# SQL needed to determine id in data set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I am not able to arrive at a reasonable SQL that will return the required id's given the following data set and rules. The id's returned should be 1, 5 and 6.

Rule1 - Return id if both Alcohol and Drug categories are present and Alcohol <= 3 and Drug = No

Rule2 - Return id if only Alcohol category is present and Alcohol <= 3

Rule3 - Return id if only Drug category is present and Drug = No

```
id  Category Value
1   Alcohol  0
1   Drug     No
2   Alcohol  5
2   Drug     Yes
3   Alcohol  3
3   Drug     Yes
4   Alcohol  5
4   Drug     No
5   Alcohol  2
6   Drug     No
7   Alcohol  5
8   Drug     Yes
```

Thanks in advance.

```
select
    dt.id
from
(
    select
        id as id
    from
        @datatbl
    group by
        id
    having
        count(*) = 1
) X
inner join @datatbl dt on
    dt.id = X.id
where
    dt.value in ('0', '1', '2', '3', 'No')
union
select
    dt1.id
from
    @datatbl dt1
    inner join (
        select
        dt.id
        from
        (
            select
                id as id
            from
                @datatbl
            group by
                id
            having
                count(*) = 2
        ) X
        inner join @datatbl dt on
            dt.id = X.id
        where
            dt.category = 'Alcohol'
            and
            dt.value in ('0', '1', '2', '3')
    ) X on
        X.id = dt1.id
where
    dt1.category = 'Drug'
    and
    dt1.value in ('No')
```

Comment: I added the SQL I am currently working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rule1:**

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
  AND t1.Category <> t2.Category AND t2.Category = 'Drug'
WHERE t1.Category = 'Alcohol' AND t1.Value <= 3 AND t2.Value = 'No'
```

**Rule2:**

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t1
LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
  AND t1.Category <> t2.Category AND t2.Category = 'Drug'
WHERE t1.Category = 'Alcohol' AND t1.Value <= 3 AND t2.Category IS NULL
```

**Rule3:**

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t1
RIGHT JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
  AND t1.Category <> t2.Category AND t2.Category = 'Drug'
WHERE t2.Value = 'No' AND t1.Category IS NULL
```

Comment: I think your result for rule2 will have an overlap with your result for rule1.

Comment: **user481779**, I modified my answer for **Rule2**.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Much more elegant and obvious than my solution!